# Manually setting the legend color and text for multi-layer plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been dabbling with r on and off for the past 2 years, and only recently began using ggplot for building graphs. I am stuck with my situation described below:

I have a multilayer plot, where all data is in the same dataframe referenced in the initial ggplot call.

- Layer 1 = Points
- Layer 2 = Avg trend
- Layer 3 = Derivative of the trend
- Layer 4&5 = Prediction interval of the Points given the average trend

What I want to do is manually adjust the legend text to reflect the names and the colors/geom for each layer (layer4&5 can be one reference). When I to do this the legend for the geom_lines all come back as red.

The other issue is that I want to rename the gradient scale, but when I do the gradient turns to discrete points rather than a bar.

```
ggplot(D_ff_NWn,aes(NW_norm,FF_Det,color = CYC))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_color_gradient(guide = guide_legend(title = "Feeder Cycle"))+
  geom_line(aes(NW_norm,FF10.fit,fill="black"), color="black", show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_line(aes(NW_norm,Diff1*SCL_rg+SCL_FF[1],fill="red"), 
            color="red", show.legend = TRUE)+
  geom_line(aes(NW_norm,FF_UCL,fill="Prediction"),color="green")+
  geom_line(aes(NW_norm,FF_LCL),color="green")+
  labs(x = "Normalized Net Weight (%)")+
  scale_y_continuous("Feed Factor (g/rev)", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. - SCL_FF[1])/SCL_rg, 
                                         name = "1st Derivative ([g/rev]/%)"))+
  scale_fill_manual(name="",
                    labels = c("Avg FF (g/min)", "1st Derivative","95% Prediction"),
                    values = c("black","red","green"))+ 
  theme(axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "red"), 
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "red"))
```

So in summary, I would ideally like to have:

1. the gradient bar with my custom name got the first layer
2. a representative line for each layer with custom names

[image: Example graph]

Note: The second y axis is scaled using `SCL_FF` and `SCL_rg`

I am sure I can't add enough data to generate the image shown above to this post, but the dataframe structure is shown below.

```
 'data.frame':  16141 obs. of  19 variables:
 $ key                : Factor w/ 6 levels "ATAB","CCNa",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
 1 1 ...
 $ Process_Time       : num  5.65 5.67 5.68 5.7 5.72 ...
 $ CONC_PCT           : num  32 32 31.8 31.7 31.6 ...
 $ STATE              : Factor w/ 4 levels "Blind","Gravimetric",..: 2 2 2 2 
 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ NW                 : num  1.16 1.15 1.15 1.15 1.15 ...
 $ SRW_SP             : num  56.7 56.4 56.3 56.2 56 ...
 $ FF                 : num  2.36 2.37 2.37 2.37 2.37 ...
 $ MF                 : num  8 7.98 7.95 7.93 7.9 ...
 $ CYC                : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Max_Mass           : num  1.72 1.72 1.72 1.72 1.72 ...
 $ NW_norm            : num  0.673 0.672 0.671 0.67 0.668 ...
 $ FF_Det             : num  2.33 2.33 2.33 2.34 2.34 ...
 $ FF10.fit           : num  2.34 2.34 2.34 2.34 2.34 ...
 $ FF10.se.fit        : num  0.000121 0.000121 0.000121 0.000121 0.000121 
 ...
 $ FF10.residual.scale: num  0.00458 0.00458 0.00458 0.00458 0.00458 ...
 $ FF10.df            : num  16128 16128 16128 16128 16128 ...
 $ Diff1              : num  0.0363 0.0363 0.0361 0.0344 0.0323 ...
 $ FF_UCL             : num  2.35 2.35 2.35 2.35 2.35 ...
 $ FF_LCL             : num  2.34 2.34 2.34 2.34 2.34 ...
```

Is there something I am blatantly missing? I thought I had a decent understanding of how the ggplot layers worked.

Appreciate any help or guidance.

**Update 07May2018**

The solution described below from Z.Lin worked. I reversed the gradient bar labels and changed the "1st derivative" layer to point to hide the unwanted raster at the high end of the "Normalized Net Weight".

1. The new legend results in point/lines for all layers. Can this be adjusted. I don't understand why it must default to this
2. The other remaining issue is that the borders from using the shape detracts from the gradient bar map to the main plot. It might be ok as the main plot is a detrended version of the Feed Factor in the window plotted against "Normalized Net Weight" instead of "Process Time"

[Updated Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvdLU.jpg)

[image]

```
ggplot(D_ff_NWn, aes(x = NW_norm))+

  geom_point(aes(y = FF_Det, fill = CYC), shape = 21,stroke = 0.1) +
  geom_point(aes(y = Diff1 * SCL_rg + SCL_FF[1], colour = "1st 
    Derivative"),size=0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y = FF10.fit, colour = "Avg FF (g/min)")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = FF_UCL, colour = "95% Prediction")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = FF_LCL, colour = "95% Prediction")) +

  labs(x = "Normalized Net Weight (%)")+
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Feed Factor (g/rev)", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. - SCL_FF[1])/SCL_rg, 
                                         name = "1st Derivative ([g/rev]/%)")) +
  scale_fill_gradient(name = "Feeder Cycle",guide = guide_colourbar(reverse = 
                                                                      TRUE))+
  scale_colour_manual(name = "",
                      values = c("Avg FF (g/min)" = "black", 
                                 "1st Derivative" = "red",
                                 "95% Prediction" = "green"))+ 

  theme(axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "red"), 
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "red"))
```

Comment: This is very difficult to answer without a minimal reproducible example (i.e., include some sample data please! :))

Comment: If you include your picture as a link, one of us here can help to edit & show it as an image in your question. O/w, as erocoar has already noted, please show some data. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) if you need further directions on how to do that.

Comment: I have added the graph link and the structure of the dataset, Is there any more I can do to get some expert help on this?

Answer (score 2):

Without actual data to test, this is my best guess for what can work for you:

```
ggplot(D_ff_NWn, 
       aes(x = NW_norm))+

  geom_point(aes(y = FF_Det, fill = CYC), shape = 21, colour = alpha("black", 0)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = FF10.fit, colour = "Avg FF (g/min)")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Diff1 * SCL_rg + SCL_FF[1], colour = "1st Derivative")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = FF_UCL, colour = "95% Prediction")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = FF_LCL, colour = "95% Prediction")) +

  labs(x = "Normalized Net Weight (%)")+
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Feed Factor (g/rev)", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. - SCL_FF[1])/SCL_rg, 
                                         name = "1st Derivative ([g/rev]/%)")) +
  scale_fill_gradient(name = "Feeder Cycle")+
  scale_colour_manual(name = "",
                      values = c("Avg FF (g/min)" = "black", 
                                 "1st Derivative" = "red",
                                 "95% Prediction" = "green")) + 

  theme(axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "red"), 
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "red"))
```

If this works, explanations are below for several issues I observed in your code:

**Issue 1 - You want to specify different colour legends for the `geom_point()` & `geom_line()` layers**

If you check `?geom_line`, you can see that `colour` is listed among the aesthetics that it understands, but `fill` is not. This means that a `fill = red` (or some other colour) line in `geom_line(aes(...))` would be ignored.

On the other hand, `geom_point` understands both `colour` and `fill`. The default point shape is coloured based on the `colour` aesthetic, but there are other shapes that are coloured based on the `fill` aesthetic, with their outlines based on the `colour` aesthetic instead.

[image: shapes]

(Image sourced from [here](http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/shape). Shapes 21-25 accept `fill` for their colours, & `colour` for their outlines.)

To address issue 1, choose a shape from 21-25, set `geom_point`'s colour using `aes(fill = CYC)`, and leave `aes(colour = something)` for your respective `geom_line` layers.

**Issue 2 - The order of the manually stated legend labels is probably wrong**

I see you know that using something like `aes(fill = "some value")` in conjunction with `scale_fill_manual()` allows you to manually specify the aesthetic mapping, but the order of values in your code is:

- `aes(fill = "black")` (layer 2)
- `aes(fill = "red")` (layer 3)
- `aes(fill = "Prediction")` (layer 4)

while the order in  your manual scale is:

```
scale_fill_manual(name="", 
                  labels = c("Avg FF (g/min)", "1st Derivative","95% Prediction"),
                  values = c("black","red","green"))
```

Ignoring the `colour` vs. `fill` problem for the moment, we can see that the alphabetical order of values listed here is `c("black", "Prediction", "red")`. `scale_fill_manual()` has no way of knowing that `Prediction` is supposed to be mapped to `green`; it will simply take the list of values in alphabetical order, & match them sequentially to the labels / values listed herein.

To address issue 2, use a named vector for the `values` parameter in `scale_XXX_manual` instead.

(I also recommend using the labels as values in the various `geom_line(aes(fill = "some value"))` layers, and remove `labels = c(...)` from `scale_XXX_manual` all together. I think it's neater that way.)

**Issue 3 - You explicitly asked for a colour legend in discrete points, rather than a colour bar**

There are two different legend-related functions in `ggplot2`, `guide_legend` and `guide_colourbar`. The former creates a discrete scale, while the latter a continuous bar. By default, `scale_XXX_gradient` actually uses the colourbar option, but the line `scale_color_gradient(guide = guide_legend(title = "Feeder Cycle"))` overrode that.

To address issue 3, you can:

- replace `guide_legend(title = "some title")` with `guide_colourbar(title = "some title")`, or;
- simply leave it out all together, and specify the legend name with `scale_XXX_gradient(name = "some title")`.

**(minor) Issue 4 - Top level aesthetic mappings**

In your code, every `geom` layer's aesthetic mappings begin with `NW_norm` for `x`, followed by a different variable for `y`.

Since `x = NW_norm` is common to all layers, it should be stated in the top level `ggplot()` call, and **only** there. All subsequent layers would inherit that, unless there's a local `aes(x = some.other.variable)` mapping to override it.

Since `y = something` is different for each layer, there's no need for it to be in the top level call. Every `geom` layer should have its own aesthetic mapping for `y`, named **explicitly** as `aes(y = something, ...)` rather than `aes(something, ...)`

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. Only issue now is that the border used from shape = 21 hides the actual gradient as shown in the update inserted above.

Comment: @AnthonyTantuccio Try adding `colour = alpha("black", 0)` to the `geom_point` line? I'll update my solution.